# Can the Cisco VPN API be accessed from VBA?

Tags: api, vba, vpn, cisco

There is an API for [Cisco VPN](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client500_501/release/notes/51client.html#wp1549190) (vpnapi.dll). Is it possible to use this API from VBA code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried declaring it and it didn't work. The answer appears to be no.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if CISCO VPM supports it, however you can give it a try by declaring the API in VBA similar to how you declare Win32 API's

http://www.your-save-time-and-improve-quality-technologies-online-resource.com/win32-vba-api.html

Comment: Thanks or your comment Nilesh. I tried it and it didn't work. Maybe it's because vpnapi.dll is written in C#.